# Laravel 5.3 how to redirect to default error page

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

I have created a default error page for the Laravel installation that is located in folder `views/errors`.

On the same folder, I have other error pages like `404.blade.php`, `503.blade.php` etc

The redirection is handled with no issue for the `pages/errors` that already exist e.g. 404 not found error.

I want for all other errors to redirect the users to a default error page that is located in the same folder `view/errors/general.blade.php`

I've overridden function `renderHttpException` on `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

```
protected function renderHttpException(HttpException $e)
{
   if (! view()->exists("errors.{$e->getStatusCode()}")) {
      return response()->view('errors.general', ['exception' => $e], 500,    
      $e->getHeaders());
   }
    return parent::renderHttpException($e);
 }
```

With this one when an error occurs and the error page doesn't exist I redirect the user to the general error page.

The issue is that it doesn't work. All other error pages work fine. When another error occurs I get the

> "Whoops, looks like something went wrong".

Comment: I want to replace the "Whooops" page with my own page. I want to use 404 error page but for all other errors i want to display the general error page.

Answer (score 2):

Use [abort](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/errors#http-exceptions) function in laravel like following and pass your HTTP Exception code:

```
abort(404,'Page not found.');
```

It will redirect to your files in following location :

```
resources/views/errors/404.blade.php
```

Comment: Laravel has its own error handling. Instead of showing the default "Whoops" page i want to show mine

Comment: Try to import the `HttpException` class with use `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException` at the top of the file.

Comment: This is the best answer! In Laravel if you want to show your own error page you just need to create that page inside `resources/views/errors/<error_code>.blade.php` and then just call it with `abort(<error_code>);`

Comment: So the solution is to create 200 views?

Answer (score 2):

On your Handler (app/Exceptions/Handler.php)
You can redirect to a default view:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception){
    if ($exception) {
            return response()->view('errors.custom',);
        }
}
```

You'll need to handle your HTTP errors here too, so then will redirect to another page, but other errors to the custom page.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

In laravel you can go to `App/Exceptions/Handler.php` and at the bottom the render function can be edited to use a custom view.

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    return view('somview');
}
```

Comment: I want to replace the "Whooops" page with my own page. I want to use 404 error page but for all other errors i want to display the general error page. I know how error pages are created

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked, for me, at least.
Edit function render in app/Exceptions/Handler.php

and add this code:

```
        if ($exception instanceof \ErrorException) {
             return response()->view("errors.general");
        }
```

Now all custom errors work fine like 404 and all other errors for which i don't have a custom error page redirect to the general page